# Why does the title (of the template in use) remain, while I have changed it in <head>?

Tags: jekyll, html-head, html-title

While inspecting the HTML rendering of my website. I discovered that the meta description, rendered by the "Jekyll SEO tag" in `<head>`, shows the old title (shown here below) of the Jekyll template I used to build my website.

```
<title>Airspace | Human centric marketing for p2p & social impact startups</title>
```

In the following screenshot you can see the "Airspace" appearing.

**[image: "Airspace" does not belong there]**

Problem = that at some times it will show this title, which can confuse my clients.

Here is the `<head>` of my repo https://github.com/bomengeduld/zentribes.org/blob/master/_includes/head.html

Everything looks good here:

```
> <meta name="description" content="As a one-stop agency, we deliver a
> full spectrum of online & offline marketing services.">
> 
> 
> <title>Human centric marketing for p2p & social impact
> startups</title>
> 
> {% seo %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I render your website locally with `jekyll s`, I am seeing you are getting two `<title>` elements.  One is from your `head.html` [1] and the second one is coming from using the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin's `title:` in your `_config.yml` [2][4].  The `Airspace` portion of the title is coming from the Jekyll front matter in your `index.html` [3].

I assume you want to remove one of these two `<title>` elements.

[1] https://github.com/bomengeduld/zentribes.org/blob/72351fe0ac0bf1ea77226e4f3dcd95f3daeec948/_includes/head.html#L7

[2] https://github.com/bomengeduld/zentribes.org/blob/72351fe0ac0bf1ea77226e4f3dcd95f3daeec948/_config.yml#L17

[3] https://github.com/bomengeduld/zentribes.org/blob/72351fe0ac0bf1ea77226e4f3dcd95f3daeec948/index.html#L3

[4] https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/usage.md#usage